# Regex Replace <>

Tags: regex

```
<update+zrdpcvplo=1e@facebookmail.com>
Reply-To:   <a href="mailto:noreply@facebookmail.com">noreply </a>
To:     <a href="mailto:susno.duandtjuk@gmail.com">Susno Duandtjuk </a>
```

I want to find <> that is not `<a href="..."></a>`

Because i need to replace it with `&lt;` `&gt;`.

How to find only `<>` that does not contain a href, like `<update+zrdpcvplo=1e@facebookmail.com>`

Comment: What's the expected output for the above input?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be using regexp on HTML but I guess something like this will work

```
var str = '<update+zrdpcvplo=1e@facebookmail.com>' + "\n" +
          'Reply-To:   <a href="mailto:noreply@facebookmail.com">noreply </a>' + "\n" +
          'To:     <a href="mailto:susno.duandtjuk@gmail.com">Susno Duandtjuk </a>';

var re  = /<(?!a|\/a)([^>]+)>/g;

var out = str.replace(re, "&lt;$1&gt;");

console.log(out);
```

Output

```
&lt;update+zrdpcvplo=1e@facebookmail.com&gt;
Reply-To:   <a href="mailto:noreply@facebookmail.com">noreply </a>
To:     <a href="mailto:susno.duandtjuk@gmail.com">Susno Duandtjuk </a>
```

Regexp visual

[image: /<(?!a|/a)([^>]+)>/g]

Comment: This will also replace the `</a>`'s though. Your output is not what I see when I run your script in console.